# How to install konsole on Cent OS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, kde-plasma, konsole

I have Cent OS 7. Since konsole tool is in kde package, I've installed it:

```
[root@localhost hduser]# sudo yum install kdebase
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos-mirror.rbc.ru
 * extras: mirror.logol.ru
 * updates: mirror.logol.ru
Package kde-baseapps-4.10.5-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But still konsole isn't installed.

```
[root@localhost hduser]# which konsole
/usr/bin/which: no konsole in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/hduser/.local/bin:/home/hduser/bin)
```

So, how can I install it?

Comment: You should ask this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete your question here, it is off-topic

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site https://unix.stackexchange.com  . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just install the konsole package.

`yum provides konsole`

Will return:

`konsole-4.10.5-4.el7.x86_64 : KDE Terminal emulator`

So you just have to install it with

`yum install konsole`

Kind regards